# onGenericMotionEvent on android button

Tags: android, android-button, multi-touch, motionevent

I did not able to set the `onGenericMotionEvent` on the button or any view. Means I did not get any response from `onGenericMotionEvent` method.

Below is my code:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMouse"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

my Java file coding:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_remote_controls);
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMouse);
}

@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

    switch (event.getAction() & event.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            Log.e("Mouse: ", "Right Click");
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.w("Mouse: ", "Left Click");
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
            if (pointerCount == 1) {
                Log.e("Mouse: ", "Move");
            } else if (pointerCount == 2) {
                Log.e("Mouse: ", "Scroll");
            }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and when i use `setOnTouchListener` on button it works perfect, but i unable to get the `MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE` on my button, When i read documents it specify that `setOnTouchListener` can not handle `MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE` so that's why i want to use the `onGenericMotionEvent` on my button to get `MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE` action.

or any other way to implements `MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE` on the button?

But i don't know how can do that, please help

**EDITED**

By Android Button, I want to simulate the real mouse, Means when user dragged over it than i want to move my laptop mouse.

When i use `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:` it works and it move the my laptop mouse, but before my mouse move it change the location of laptop mouse pointer where it is click on button, so ignoring that Android provide `ACTION_HOVER_MOVE` it is not perform `ACTION_DOWN` unlike `ACTION_MOVE`

Comment: what do you need ACTION_HOVER_MOVE for?

Comment: @pskink, i want the simulate real mouse, Means when user move finger on the button at thta time i want to move laptop mouse.

Comment: @pskink, in short i want to handle all the mouse events from my android button.

Comment: then override `Activity#dispatchTouchEvent`

Comment: @pskink, it's also does not work for me, it does not handle the ACTION_HOVER_MOVE but is handle other all events

Comment: then see `dispatchGenericMotionEvent`

Comment: @pskink, it still does not work. any other way ?

Comment: what device that support hover events are you using?

Comment: currently,i am using Gionee P3 mobile phone

Comment: so it doesn't support hover events, or it has attached a stylus or something?

Comment: so how can i applied hover events on every smart phone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84446/discussion-between-kalpesh-rajai-and-pskink).

Comment: Hello @pskink, please help how i can do that??

Comment: @KalpeshRajai  were you able to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey as I got your problem you want a hover effect to work on button when you touch on it.

You can use the code below just pass instance of your Button in this method and also customise colors for hover effects:

```
public void buttonEffect(View button){
        button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00BFFF"),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this help you...!!!

Comment: I don't want any effect on my button, I want to just handle the `MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE` on my button, please can you help me to do that?